# can't change month number to month name using scale_x

Tags: r

This is my dataset:

```
temperature <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Year= c(1998,1998,1998,1998,1998,1998,1998,1998,1998,1998,1998,1998,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002),
  Month = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
  Temperature = c(5,6,7,12,15,16,27,28,22,10,11,6,6,6,7,13,16,15,25,26,24,12,11,4,5,6,7,12,15,17,28,30,22,10,11,7,7,7,7,12,18,17,25,24,20,3,3,4,5,6,7,12,15,16,27,28,22,10,11,6),
  check.names = FALSE
)

temperature$date = as.Date(paste(temperature$Year, temperature$Month,1), format = "%Y %m %d")
```

This is the code I used

```
ggplot(temperature,
       aes(
         x = date,
         y = Temperature,
         colour=as.factor(Month),
         group=1
       )) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Time series") +
  scale_x_date(
    date_breaks = "year", 
    date_labels = "%Y", 
    date_minor_breaks = "month"
  ) +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Temperature")
```

Now the months were in number and not in name
I used that code

```
ggplot(temperature,
       aes(
         x = date,
         y = Temperature,
         colour=as.factor(Month),
         group=1
       )) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Time series") +
  scale_x_date(
    date_breaks = "year", 
    date_labels = "%Y", 
    date_minor_breaks = "month", labels=month.abb
  ) +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Temperature")
```

But seems not work. I thougt that I have to change something in scale_x_date?

How can I change that month names came into the legend?

The problem is that the legend shows month number instead of month name

Comment: In your plot you show `x = date`, but the data you show doesn't have a `date` column. Did you make a `date` column? Does it have class `Date`?

Comment: yes, i did it, I correct it now

Comment: Yes I want that the x-Axis shows the years, but I colored the line graph and a legend is next to the line  graph which shows the month, but I would like to have month name and not month number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a color scale, I would specify the `labels` when you convert month to `factor`:

```
ggplot(temperature,
       aes(
         x = date,
         y = Temperature,
         colour=factor(Month, levels = 1:12, labels = month.abb),
         group=1
       )) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Time series") +
  scale_x_date(
    date_breaks = "year", 
    date_labels = "%Y", 
    date_minor_breaks = "month"
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "Year",
    y = "Temperature",
    color = "Month"
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want month abbreviations to appear in the legend, you'll need to modify the variable you are using to set the color. you call `as.factor(Month)` in your code which makes it a factor with levels 1 through 12. Changing to `factor(Month, labels = month.abb)` will update your legend. Note you could make this more readable by performing this factoring step on the data before plotting.

```
ggplot(temperature,
   aes(
     x = date,
     y = Temperature,
     colour=factor(Month, labels = month.abb),
     group=1
   )) +
geom_line() +
ggtitle("Time series") +
scale_x_date(
date_breaks = "year", 
date_labels = "%Y", 
date_minor_breaks = "month"
) +
xlab("Year") +
ylab("Temperature")
```